# Изменение параметра в адресной строке

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Помогите пожалуйста :(
Например, мы перешли по ссылке: `site.ru/script.php?page=1`
 
Как сделать, чтобы на сайте отображалось: 
`<a href='site.ru/script.php?page=2'>`, т.е. чтобы "`page=`" менялся?

Answer (score 1):

```
$page=(isset($_GET["page"])&&is_int($_GET["page"])&&($_GET["page"]>0))?$_GET["page"]:1;
echo '<a href="site.ru/script.php?page='.($page+1).'">';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$page = isset($_REQUEST['page']) ? $_REQUEST['page'] : 0;
echo "<a href='site.ru/script.php?page=".($page+1)."'>"
```

как то так ...

Неужели до этого тяжело дойти ? :)

Answer (score -1):

Например так:

```
$page = $_REQUEST['page'];
if ( (int)$page != $page ) $page = 0;
echo '<a href="site.ru/script.php?page='.($page+1).'">';
```

Comment: В данном случае тут она действительно не нужна. Выполняется арифметическое действие

Comment: А когда это запретили арифметику с **float**?

Comment: Не понимаю, нафига обращаться к $_REQUEST? А если потребуется добавить еще переменные $_COOKIE["page"] и $_POST["page"]? )

Comment: @ImirofF, А вы готовы поручиться что данные будут приходить из конкретного метода передачи?

Comment: Согласно задаче, данные берутся из $_GET. Если юзер их пришлет посредством $_POST, засунет в куки - то это точно тест на уязвимость.